# Change files delimiter from TAB and Pipe(|) to CTRL-A

Tags: awk, sed

I have two `.txt` files, one with `TAB` as field delimiter and another with `|` as field delimiter.

I want to change the delimiter from `TAB` to `CTRL-A` and save as `.txt` file for the first file and for the second file change the delimiter from `|` to `CTRL-A` and save as `.txt` file.

These two files are separate files.

How can we do it using `awk` or `sed`?

Comment: See http://www.theunixschool.com/2012/09/examples-how-to-change-delimiter-of-file-Linux.html 

It contains relevant examples of both awk and sed.

Comment: What do you mean by Ctrl-A? What character does it represnet?

Answer (score 3):

For file one, try:

```
cat file1 | sed -e 's/\t/\x01/g' >file1.txt
```

For file two, try

```
cat file2 | sed -e 's/\|/\x01/g' >file2.txt
```

Comment: I had to do it that way... I can never get ctrl+v,ctrl+a to work :-)

Answer (score 2):

This is a great use for `tr`:

```
tr '\t' '\001' <file1 >file1-new
```

That will perform the transformation from horizontal tabs on file1 and output the results to file1-new. You can do the same thing with pipes.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative using `perl`:

Replacing pipes:

```
echo "a|b|c" | perl -pe '$c=chr(1); s/\|/$c/g' | cat -A
a^Ab^Ac$
```

Replacing tabs:

```
echo -e  "a\tb\tc" | perl -pe '$c=chr(1); s/\t/$c/g' | cat -A
a^Ab^Ac$
```